# $\int_0^1 \mathbb{1}_{\{f(t) >0\}}dt$ on $C[0,1]$ is continuous except on a set of Wiener measure 0.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, wiener-measure

The question is the following

> This question considers the occupation time of Brownian motion on the positive half time $\int_0^1 \mathbb{1}_{\{B_t >0\}}dt$.
>
> Show that the functional $\psi$ on $C[0,1]$ defined by $$\psi(f)=\int_0^1 \mathbb{1}_{\{f(t) >0\}}dt$$ is continuous except on a set of Wiener measure 0.

I have no idea how to translate this to an actual argument. How exactly does a set of Wiener measure 0 look like?

Comment: Can you maybe add some content, where do you encounter this problem, I have the feeling that you might be more interested into the question if the occupation measure of Brownian Motion might be continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue measure? Otherwise I believe the zero set of Brownian Motion $\mathcal{Z} = \{t \geq 0 : B_t(\omega) = 0\}$ should be a set of measure zero regarding the Wiener measure, no?